# IOS SDK Facebook SSO - User logs out from Facebook outside app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

The instructions on using Single Sign-On (SSO) with the Facebook IOS SDK are to save the access token and expiration date in `fbDidLogin` and use them on subsequent calls to avoid unnecessary logins.

But what if the user logs out of Facebook outside the app (e.g. in the Facebook app or in Safari)? The app doesn't know about this, so it tries to use the saved token and expiration date, and to my surprise - they are still valid and the app can access the user's data even though the user has logged out.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there is no way to do this. each FB login a user makes is specific to the client they logged in with. A FB login is not universal across all clients. The FB token you get from the SDK is a token for that user with your app. So if a user logs out of FB in their browser or another app, they have not logged of FB from your app so the token will remain valid until it expires or the app or user explicitly logs out from the context of your app.

Not sure why you are concerned about this. Generally you would want your users to remain logged in. If you have a reason you don't want this don't request "offline_access" permission when you authorize a FB user and you can also logout and de-authorize the user via the FB API based on whatever criteria you deem appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is, I'm not sure that "I would want my users to remain logged in". This is not up to me to decide, it's up to the user. I believe that if the user has logged out of Facebook anywhere on a device, he or she shouldn't be able to access Facebook from anywhere on that device until he or she loggs in again. I'll try to remove offline_access and see if it helps.

Comment: you are thinking about this the wrong way. conceptually, when a user logs into your app (by whatever method, including FB) they are only logging in to your app. For example, if a user logged in to your app via FB and then went to facebook.com would they expect to be logged in? of course not. likewise, if they log out of your app, would they expect to be logged out of facebook.com. No. e.g. it is up to the user. they will log in/out of your app as they see fit. this doesn't affect any other logins they've done with other apps/sites.

Comment: Usually the user does not log into my app at all. He has already logged in using the Facebook app or perhaps some other Facebook-enabled app. That's the whole idea of SSO. If the user does happen to log in to FB from my app (which means that my app was the first one to use FB) and then goes to facebook.com, he or she SHOULD be logged in. There's no point in using SSO otherwise.

Comment: The point of SSO is to allow you to authenticate a user via existing credentials ( eg FB) without needing to enter Username/pwd. They are still logging in explicitly by allowing SSO to work the first time they authorize your app to do this. That auth is app specific and can be revoked by the user at any time. IMHO thus should be bet app, not universal. SSO would suck if logging out of one app logged me out of everything. If a user wants to globally revoke all auths they can do that via FB privacy settings.

Comment: meant "IMHO this should be per app" above.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "Single sign-on (SSO) is a property of access control of multiple related, but independent software systems. With this property a user logs in once and gains access to all systems without being prompted to log in again at each of them. Single sign-off is the reverse property whereby a single action of signing out terminates access to multiple software systems." What you're suggesting is Single Sign On but individual Sign Offs, which IMO doesn't make much sense. In addition, signing off in an app doesn't revoke authorizations, it just signs the user off.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm suggesting. I am merely describing why the FB SDK works the way it does. SSO means you enter a username/pwd once. In the case of the FB SDK, you still need to auth each client and even when auth'ed, each client has it's own token, not a shared token for all clients. You can debate this with me all you like but this is simply not how the FB SDK works (or should work) on iOS. If other SSO's systems work differently so be it. Wikipedia is not correct (or at least not definitive) in this case. Signing in to your app via the FB iOS SDK will not sign you into other apps.

Comment: Logging on and authorizing are not the same. If the user isn't logged on and the app isn't authorized yet, the user needs to do both. If he has already logged on somehow outside the app, he only needs to authorize the app. Once authorized, if he then logs off, he only need to log on again - the authorization doesn't expire. SSO by itself has nothing to do with authorization: applications can (and need to) be authorized by the user with or without SSO. But if I use SSO and I switch for example from user A to user B in FB, this should be propagated to all FB apps, otherwise bad things happen.

Comment: I am fully aware of what SSO and auth are. In a browser (or when clients share a token) things work the way you describe. In iOS each app has it's own token so the closest you can get is to re-auth with FB every time you launch or resume from the background. If you're ok with that user experience then go for it.

Comment: I think SSO is a misnomer in Facebook's case. A user is not signed in to the other apps by virtue of being signed in to Facebook. The apps need to be authorised in addition to authenticating you. This is different from SSO IMHO.